# Display a modal Pop up in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently developing an MVC project that requires giving the client 30 days trial. As from 5 days to the end of the trial, i want to start displaying warning messages to the user. I registered a *Subscription Attribute* which works just like the Authorize Attribute in ASP.NET MVC.

**How it works:**

While the client is working i check `if(trial period <= 5 days)`.

If true, an `HttpSubscriptionExpiredResult` Action Result is returned, which produces a customized status code. This status code is intercepted by the `SubscriptionModule`, which then redirects to the warning page.

**My Needs:**

I want the warning Action Method to return a modal pop up (or just a pop up). Or simply put: I want the warning message displayed in a modal pop up. This will prevent disrupting the client's work. How do i achieve this?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal

Comment: just create conditional statement in your controller to inject jquery into view that pops up modal when there is less than 5 days left

Comment: You have to some jquery popups, you can't use Ajax ModalPopupExtender here

Answer (score 1):

> This status code is intercepted by the SubscriptionModule, **which then redirects to the warning page**.

There are lots of methods to make an modal popup in HTML pages; the simplest one is presented at [Simple jQuery Modal Window Tutorial](http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial)

In your `warning page` put the following JavaScript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //id is the ID for the DIV you want to display it as modal window
    launchWindow(id);
});
```

It shows a nice popup window.